# Realise password phone

Tags: javascript

Hello i'm working on a new project.

i'd like to realise an HTML/CSS/javascript code to realise a mobile interface
with Pin code. Well i let you look it's quite easy to understand with the code but hard to make for me :(

like:

```
 <!-- NOCOUNT -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>

</head>


<body>

<div id="container">
<MAP NAME="menu">

<AREA id="Bouton1" SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" >
<!-- <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(2)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(3)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(4)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(5)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(6)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(7)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(8)">
<AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="" onClick="codeEnter(9)"> -->
</MAP>
<IMG SRC="tel.jpg" WIDTH=204 HEIGHT=404 BORDER=0 USEMAP="#menu">
</div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">

body
{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#000;
}


#container
    {
        display:block ;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;
        margin-top: -384px;
        margin-right:-512px;
        width:1024px;
        height:768px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        z-index:1;
        background:url();
    }



</style>
<script>
var code= "1111";
var formulaire="";
var compteur=0;
$("#Bouton1").click( function(){
        compteur++;
        formulaire = formulaire + "1";
        if(compteur == 4){
              alert(code.toString());
        }    
    });
</script>
</html>
```

But it do not work any help please ?

Comment: what does not work exactly? please update your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You miss the `<html></html>` tags around your code and `<body></body>` around the page content
2. The correct syntax is `id="1"`, not `id=1`
3. You didn't insert jQuery (to use `$()`)
   Inside `<head></head>` insert

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. Optionnal, but the tags have to be written in lower case

Edit :

```
$("#1").click( function(){
        compteur++;
        fomulaire = fomulaire + "1";
        if(compteur == 4){
              alert(code.toString());
        }    
    });
`
```

Comment: I changed all you said , thanks :) may you explain me why my var are stuck at "1" ?

Comment: Well it do not work :( , when i click on my button it shoud implement but it dont go upper than 1 and my Strings do not concat

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do, but the `code` variable is never modified (you may have an updated code to show ?)

Comment: Well code dont need to be modified , but i want to press 4 time the area and obtain the var formulaire as "1111" String , and the var compteur as "4" Int , But actually each time i click on the areamap the console return me "1" and "1"  even if i click 15194 time

Comment: well i'm trying to and the console return me 1 then 1 then 1 :/

Comment: - the `href` in id="Bouton1" area should be `href="#"` 

-the `<style></style>` should be before `<body>` (or better, in a CSS file)

- the `</body>` should be after `</script>`

Comment: (once again if it works, mark the question as "Resolved" ;) )

Comment: Sorry i was at home without network :) , Thanks for the help